# Operand Missing Variable

Tags: java, oop

```
int curFreeFrame = FrameTableEntry numFreeFrames();
```

The error states this "error ';' expected".

Everything is initialized correctly in the methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to invoke a static method, it should be :

```
int curFreeFrame = FrameTableEntry.numFreeFrames();
```

This assumes that `numFreeFrames` is a static method in `FrameTableEntry` class (which is an assumption based entirely on the naming conventions you used).

Comment: @user2980816 perhaps you should share with us what is `FrameTableEntry` (class? variable?) and what's the definition of `numFreeFrames()` method.

Comment: @user2980816 - Hint: we are not a free service for fixing compilation errors.  Try reading the error messages yourself, working out what they mean, and fixing them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious error is that you are missing the `.` so `FrameTableEntry.numFreeFrames();` makes more sense than `FrameTableEntry numFreeFrames();`.

Now, with that said, if you're still getting an error, it might that you haven't initialized the `FrameTableEntry` class.

You can do so by `FrameTableEntry f = new FrameTableEntry()` and then use it's method `numFreeFrames()` by doing `int curFreeFrame = f.numFreeFrames();`.